# Are bare objects in javascript part of the ECMAScript standard?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I've come across [this article](http://bahmutov.calepin.co/sweet-naked-objects.html) that suggests using 'bare objects' for your hashmap needs if your keys are always strings.

Bare objects are objects created using `null` as the prototype value, for instance with `Object.create(null)`. Using the object literal notation (i.e. `{}`) do not create a bare objects since they set `Object.prototype` as the prototype.

The article points out that the great thing about bare objects is that you can use them as hashmaps without having to worry about builtin keys like `toString` potentially causing bugs when using a key with the same name.

Is this behavior part of the ES5 and/or ES6 standard? That is, if I use bare objects as string key hashmaps in my code, can I rely on my code behaving in the way that I would expect? Are there any caveats to here?

Comment: Why not consult the standards yourself?

Comment: Yes, it is [part of the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5). Simple test: `Object.create(null).toString; // undefined`

Comment: Behave how exactly? If you're developing in a "closed" enviroment, for instance for the serverside, you should know what features the version of Ecma you're using supports. If it's for browsers, wouldn't it be more useful to know what browsers supports `Object.create`, as any browser supporting that can also directly create an object with a `null` prototype ?

Comment: Also, the [**ES5**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) and [**ES6**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.create) standards are basically the same for `Object.create`

Comment: What does "can I rely" mean? If some other script has altered `Object.create`, it might return an object whose [[Prototype]] is not null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, ECMA-Script 2015 and above has collections like [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). That is, in newer JavaScript implementations you don't need to simulate dictionaries/hashmaps/hashtables  with objects anymore.

> The article points out that the great thing about bare objects is that
>   you can use them as hashmaps without having to worry about builtin
>   keys like toString potentially causing bugs when using a key with the
>   same name.

The article ignores that you don't need to worry about `toString` in literal objects because there're well-supported functions to get own object's properties without walking through the prototype chain.

For example, let's say I've declared a literal object as follows: `var obj = { text: "Matias" };`.

A regular `for..in` loop would iterate `Object.prototype` properties, but `Object.keys` will iterate *own object properties* only:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(propertyName => {
    var someOwnProperty = obj[propertyName ];
});
```

In addition, a regular `for..in` could work as `Object.keys` using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```
for(var propertyName in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
       // True if property is declared on obj and not in some 
       // level of the prototype chain
    }
}
```

**AN UPDATE HERE:** @bergi is right about something. If `obj` would declare an own property `hasOwnProperty`, above `for..in` wouldn't work **because `obj.hasOwnProperty` wouldn't be [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) anymore**.

Imagine that you've the following object that would produce above described issue:

```
var obj = {
    hasOwnProperty: "hey! I'm not Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty anymore!"
};
```

That `hasOwnProperty` would hide [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Above described issue can be circumvented using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) directly with [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call):

```
for(var propertyName in obj) {
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propertyName)) {
       // True if property is declared on obj and not in some 
       // level of the prototype chain
    }
}
```

Or you could store `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` in a variable to simplify the `if` statement setting what would be `this` once the function gets called with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/bind):

```
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

for(var propertyName in obj) {
    if(hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
       // True if property is declared on obj and not in some 
       // level of the prototype chain
    }
}
```

#### A side-effect of creating bare objects and using them as prototypes

While you can create *bare objects* with `Object.create(null)`, the problem comes when a given *bare object* is the prototype of some other object:

```
var bareObject = Object.create(null, {
   text: { value: "hello world" }
});

var secondObject = Object.create(bareObject);
secondObject.text2 = "bye!";

for(var property in secondObject) {
   // WAIT, secondObject prototype is a bare object! 
   // And I can't call secondObject.hasOwnProperty to check
   // if the enumerated property is declared in the own object...    
}
```

If this isn't the case and given object is just a *bare object*, you can use `in` operator:

```
if("someProperty" in bareObject) {

}
```

Otherwise, you would need to go with calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` with `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.bind` as described above in my answer.

Anyway, as I state at the beginning of my answer, if you're working with ES2015 and above, and you're using a transpiler like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/), you can go with the new JavaScript standard collection types instead of simulating dictionaries with objects.

> Is this behavior part of the ES5 and/or ES6 standard? That is, if I
>   use bare objects as string key hashmaps in my code, can I rely on my
>   code behaving in the way that I would expect? Are there any caveats to
>   here?

`Object.create` was introduced in ECMA-Script 5. It behaves as you expect in almost any modern Web browser and NodeJS.

Comment: By calling `obj.hasOwnProperty(…)` like this, you fell exactly in the trap that the article describes. You *should* worry about keys with the same name as builtin methods. It's not about enumerability, just about collisions.

Comment: @Bergi BTW, a key called `toString` in the own object isn't a name collision, is it? It's just that own object's property has priority over the prototype's one. The result is almost the same as `Object.create(null)` if you know what's the prototype chain and the fact that you need to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` or `Object.keys` to avoid walking through the prototype chain.

Comment: So why do you use `obj.hasOwnProperty` then instead of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm referring to `obj.hasOwnProperty` which is a function of Object's prototype, isn't it? ;D

Comment: Not when there is an own property of `obj` that has priority over the prototype's one. That's what I call a collision :-)

Comment: @Bergi Well, this is subjective... For me, a naming collision occurs when you're reusing identifiers... declaring a property in the own object hides its prototype's counterpart...

Comment: Ok, whatever we call it - it's still a bug in your code :-)

Comment: @Bergi What's the bug in my code? I'm able to filter enumerable properties from the given object O_o

Comment: Your second snippet does not work on `obj`s that contain a `hasOwnProperty` key!

Comment: @Bergi Ah yeah, I see. This is a true naming collision, I can update my answer to reflect your concern!

Comment: @Bergi Well, sorry, it's still hidding `hasOwnProperty` from `Object.prototype` rather than a naming collision ;D

Comment: @Bergi Check my update, I believe that now my answer is more complete and accurate. Are you agree?

Comment: Thanks for the update, now you got me :-) Regarding "*using `Object.create(null)` […] you [still] would be forced to go with the same workaround*", the point of `Object.create(null)` is that you don't need the `hasOwnProperty` check any more because such an object *only* has own properties.

Comment: @Bergi well you would still need hasOwnProperty to check if a property exists in a given bare object

Comment: @Bergi oh and thanks too. This is what demonstrates that collaborative work is the way to go!

Comment: On bare objects you can use the `in` operator for that without any precautions :-)

Comment: @Bergi I've re-updated my answer to reflect that too! See the part of "A side-effect of creating bare objects and using them as prototypes"

Answer (score 0):

> Is this behavior part of the ES5 and/or ES6 standard?

Yes. You can find `Object.create(null)` and the behaviour of looking up / assigning properties closely specified in the ES5, ES6 and ES7 standards.

> If I use bare objects as string key hashmaps in my code, can I rely on my code behaving in the way that I would expect?

No. There is no guarantee in the standard that objects are implemented as hashmaps, and there are no complexity/performance assertions either. Implementations might have very slow property lookup on large objects.

Since ES6, you should use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects which guarantee sub-linear complexity.